# insert into .. select from in stored proc errors out on dropped column

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

MySQL version 5.5.27

UPDATE2: Pretty sure this is a big, did a test from scratch with the same behavior.  Opening bug on MySQL site and will update with results.

UPDATE: If I drop the column from the temporary table in a stored procedure, it works fine.  The problem only occurs if I drop the column by hand.

The following line fails in a stored procedure, with error:

```
mysql> insert into player_record_week select * from pr_temp;

mysql> call insert_agg_week('2013-02-26');
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'prod_gamestats.pr_temp.total_battles' in 'field list'
```

If I run it by hand it works.

```
mysql>  insert into player_record_week select * from pr_temp;
Query OK, 211708 rows affected (2.23 sec)
Records: 211708  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

If I leave the total_battles column in the temporary table it fails with an error about column count mismatch.  The table pr_temp is created by the duplicating the player_record_week table.

```
| insert_agg_week |          | CREATE PROCEDURE     `insert_agg_week`(insert_week date)
begin
delete from player_record_week where stat_week = insert_week;
delete from player_tank_record_week where stat_week = insert_week;
delete from player_ratings_week_agg where stat_week = insert_week;
delete from player_ratings_week_per where stat_week = insert_week;
delete from global_week where stat_week = insert_week;
delete from global_tank_week where stat_week = insert_week;
insert into player_record_week select * from pr_temp;
insert into player_tank_record_week select * from ptr_temp;
insert into player_ratings_week_agg select * from pratings_temp_agg;
insert into player_ratings_week_per select * from pratings_temp_per;
insert into global_week select * from global_week_temp;
insert into global_tank_week select * from global_tank_week_temp;
end | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
```

If I keep the extra column the stored procedure will error out with a column count mismatch.

If I drop the extra column, the stored procedure errors out with a reference to the column that I dropped:

```
mysql> call insert_agg_week('2013-02-26');
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'prod_gamestats.pr_temp.total_battles' in 'field list'
```

If I run the commands by hand it runs with no problems:

```
mysql> delete from player_record_week where stat_week = '2013-02-26';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from player_tank_record_week where stat_week = '2013-02-26';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from player_ratings_week_agg where stat_week = '2013-02-26';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.52 sec)

mysql> delete from player_ratings_week_per where stat_week = '2013-02-26';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> delete from global_week where stat_week = '2013-02-26';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from global_tank_week where stat_week = '2013-02-26';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>  insert into player_record_week select * from pr_temp;
Query OK, 211708 rows affected (2.23 sec)
Records: 211708  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>  insert into player_tank_record_week select * from ptr_temp;
Query OK, 1618240 rows affected (25.61 sec)
Records: 1618240  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>  insert into player_ratings_week_agg select * from pratings_temp_agg;
Query OK, 211708 rows affected (1.86 sec)
Records: 211708  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>  insert into player_ratings_week_per select * from pratings_temp_per;
Query OK, 41648 rows affected (0.39 sec)
Records: 41648  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>  insert into global_week select * from global_week_temp;
Query OK, 21 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 21  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>  insert into global_tank_week select * from global_tank_week_temp;
Query OK, 257 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 257  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Here are the two tables:

```
mysql> describe pr_temp;
+------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| player_id              | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| stat_week              | date                  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| insert_date            | date                  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| tier_weight            | float                 | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| tier_weight_adj        | float                 | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| battles_count          | int(10) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| wins                   | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| losses                 | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| survived_battles       | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| spotted                | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hits_percents          | tinyint(3) unsigned   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| capture_points         | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| damage_dealt           | int(10) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| frags                  | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dropped_capture_points | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| max_xp                 | smallint(5) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| battle_avg_xp          | smallint(5) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| xp                     | int(10) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| integrated_rating      | smallint(5) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| efficiency             | smallint(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| efficiency_adj         | smallint(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| wn7                    | smallint(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| wn7_adj                | smallint(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe player_record_week;
+------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| player_id              | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| stat_week              | date                  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| insert_date            | date                  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| tier_weight            | float                 | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| tier_weight_adj        | float                 | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| battles_count          | int(10) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| wins                   | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| losses                 | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| survived_battles       | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| spotted                | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hits_percents          | tinyint(3) unsigned   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| capture_points         | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| damage_dealt           | int(10) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| frags                  | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dropped_capture_points | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| max_xp                 | smallint(5) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| battle_avg_xp          | smallint(5) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| xp                     | int(10) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| integrated_rating      | smallint(5) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| efficiency             | smallint(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| efficiency_adj         | smallint(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| wn7                    | smallint(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| wn7_adj                | smallint(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug in MySQL, fixed in 5.6.6; metadata isn't updated after initial procedure run.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32868

Workaround from the bug report is to flush the cache:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `tmpview` AS SELECT 1;